In Program.cs Uri is empty while is running
When I startup the application everything is okay.
But sometime while the application is running this error appearce after an api call,
it look like the problem appearce not during some call but after that.
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'uriString'),    at System.ArgumentNullException.Throw(String paramName)
   at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
   at Program.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Main>b__3(HttpClient c) in Program.cs:line 121
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpClientFactory.CreateClient(String name)
   at Services.Services.ServicesA..ctor(ILogger logger, IHttpClientFactory factory, IOptions`1 baseConfiguration) in \ServicesA.cs:line 29
   at Services.Services.ServicesChildOfSerciceA..ctor(ILogger logger, IHttpClientFactory factory, IOptions`1 baseConfiguration) in \ServicesChildOfSerciceA.cs:line 36
   at ResolveService(ILEmitResolverBuilderRuntimeContext, ServiceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(ServiceIdentifier serviceIdentifier, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at lambda_method35(Closure, IServiceProvider, Object[])
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at WebService.Middleware.ConfigureTokenMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext, IOptions`1 baseConfiguration, ILogger logger) in ConfigurationMiddleware.cs:line 69
   at WebService.Middleware.ExceptionMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext) in ExceptionMiddleware.cs:line 23

line 121
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("ResourceUrl", 
    c => c.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.Configuration
                                  .GetSection("Urls")
                                  .GetSection("ResourceUrl").Value!));

How I inject the httpclient in the constructor of the service.
public class ServicesA
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _factory;

    protected readonly ILogger _logger;

    public HttpClient ResourceUrl { get; }

    public HttpClient ResourceUrl2 { get; }

    public BaseConfiguration BaseConfiguration;

    public ArxBaseServices(ILogger logger, IHttpClientFactory factory, IOptions<BaseConfiguration> baseConfiguration)
    {
            _logger = logger;
            _factory = factory;
            ResourceUrl = _factory.CreateClient("ResourceUrl");
            ResourceUrl2 = _factory.CreateClient("ResourceUrl2");
            BaseConfiguration = baseConfiguration.Value; 
    }
}

UPDATE
I understand the problem is when the application try to create the instance of the httpclient, the httpfactory go to the program to get the url but it found empty
BaseServices constructor Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'uriString'),    at System.ArgumentNullException.Throw(String paramName)
   at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
   at WebService.Program.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Main>b__2(HttpClient c) Program.cs:line 119
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpClientFactory.CreateClient(String name)
   at Services.Services.BaseServices..ctor(ILogger logger, IHttpClientFactory factory, IOptions`1 baseConfiguration) in BaseServices.cs:line 42


builder.Configuration.GetSection("Urls").GetSection("ResourceUrl").Value is returning null. I see you added ! to suppress the compiler specifically warning you about that... don't do that.

Not at the start of the application because all services that use the httpclient works fine.

@Dai That doesn't explain why it works initially and then stops working unless the configuration is changing or something. I suspect there's more than 1 HttpClient in play and Snuden is confusing the two (or more).

@RobIII Notice that it's for a named HttpClient - so simply injecting HttpClient using DI won't invoke that specific instance configurator. It's also possible that the IConfiguration used in the application is being mutated at runtime such that GetSection("ResourceUrl") is non-null during ConfigureServices() but null when it comes to actually instantiating+configuring that named HttpClient.

@Dai Still, removing (or adding) the null suppression operator (though I agree it shouldn't be used) doesn't explain it working initially and it then stopping to work. And, yes, as I said, OP is probably confusing one or more HttpClients or, also like I said, the configuration is changing during runtime.

@RobIII IHttpClientFactory's configuration is runtime-mutable which doesn't make troubleshooting this any easier.

We'll need to wait and see what OP has to say then ;-)

@RobIII So yes there are 2 addHttpClient, but both inside the appsettings.json if I go to look the values , they exist.

But the appsettings.json is read more than once so?
Is it read everytimes it is call ?
